# fetch call to API with absolute URLs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, dns, fetch

I was recently developing a website where the set up was: a static React bundle handling FE logic (served from Cloudfront), and a Docker container running a Flask application listening on Elastic Beanstalk.

In the React code, i was making a `fetch()` call with an absolute path to the API backend (see, `fetch(https://mywebsitehere.com/api/cool_endpoint`.

For some reason, in production and hitting the AWS server (through some redirect behaviors between Cloudfront and EB), I kept getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`! I had no idea why. What was weird was that when I hit `https://mywebsitehere.com/api/cool_endpoint` directly through the browser, my API worked just fine.

Eventually I figured out that the solution was to add `www` to the absolute URL. Everything worked, but I still have no idea why.

It works, but I would like to understand what's going on. Does chrome automatically fill in that `www`? Did the lack of the `www` in the original cause the fetch machinery to fail to resolve, and thus cause an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`?

Let me know what y'all think!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from [a recent Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/mi457y/why_im_getting_this_alert_so_much/gt393we/?context=2) is that `https://www.example.com` is not the same as `https://example.com`, and if one redirects to the other, it's only because it's been loaded into the [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) preload list specifically to create that redirect.

Presumably, the website you're hitting hasn't got that set up.